# POST api SOAP Ionic V3 error: "has been blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: webservice, typescript, soap, ionic3, cors

**No controlo el servidor donde hago las peticiones.**

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy tratando de hacer una petición a una API SOAP desde Ionic.

con el siguiente código:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', this.testBaseURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Consulta");

xhr.onload = () => {
  // codigo después de obtener datos
}
xhr.send(param);
```

el problema es que me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[nombre del servidor]' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Cabe mencionar que este código SI FUNCIONA en web si me meto a modo inseguro o utilizo alguna extensión de google chrome**, pero no quiero eso, quiero que funcione normalmente para que se pueda usar en producción web y en Android.
en IOS si me funciona y no se por qué...

Intente hacer lo del proxy, pero no funciona, estoy desesperado, llevo 2 días completos atorado con esto, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Info IONIC:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
```

Comment: Has chequeado los HEADERS del lado servidor???

Comment: agrega en el header `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST", "OPTIONS");`